# Prove $4(x^2+1)^3 \leq 5(x^3+2)^2$

Tags: calculus, analysis

I need to prove that $4(x^2+1)^3 \leq 5(x^3+2)^2$ ,  for all $x\geq 0$, in the context of an introductory analysis course. I thought I could somehow use convex functions to prove this, but I simply cannot get it to work. Hints anyone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By [Holder's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder%27s_inequality)  $$(x^3+2)(x^3+2)(4+1)\ge {\left (\sqrt[3]{x^3\cdot x^3 \cdot 4}+\sqrt[3]{2\cdot 2\cdot 1}\right)}^3=4{(x^2+1)}^3$$

Done!

Comment: thank you thank you thank you! I knew it had to do with convex functions!

Comment: @Chris you are welcome,holder kills it!

Answer (score 2):

**Hint :**

$$ 5(x^3+2)^2 - 4(x^2+1)^3 = (x-2)^2(x^4+4x^3+4x+4)$$

Answer (score -1):

we must prove :
$$4x^6+12x^4+12x^2+4 \leq 5x^6+20x^3+20$$
which rewrites to :
$$x^6-12x^4+20x^3-12x^2+16 \ge0$$
or :
$$(x-2)(x^5+2x^4-8x^3+4x^2-4x-8) \geq 0$$
or :
$$(x-2)^2(x^4+4x^3+4x+4)\geq 0$$
which is clearly true, with equality at $x=2$

Comment: It is not correct to begin with the conclusion.

Comment: i do not understand what you are saying. 
i said the problem is basically saying to prove 
$$(x-2)^2(x^4+4x^3+4x+4)\ge 0$$
which is clearly true.

Comment: Just explain your first line : "we have $4x^6+12x^4+12x^2+4 \leq 5x^6+20x^3+20$". This is precisely what the OP wants to ask, if you begin by stating that *we have* that, then your reasoning is weird.

Comment: yes i got what you are saying. and i have edited my solution. i belive every thing is fixed now?

Comment: Yes, it is better, thanks for editing. But in my opinion, it would be even better by writing explicit equivalence signs ($\Leftrightarrow$), or by writing your reasoning in the other direction.

Comment: i am quite new to latex. and i just know some basic codes.
i searched a little in some places but couldn't find a good manual to write latex. so it is the most i can do ...